# What number comes after 0.10? 0.2 or 0.11?

Tags: number-systems

What number comes after 0.10? 0.2 or 0.11? Decimal realm is confusion for me, help:)

Comment: Rational (or real) numbers do not have immediate successors unless we pick a strange ordering.

Comment: Or $0.101$   :-) ${}{}$

Comment: And this isn't unique to $\mathbb{R}$. Given a rational number there's no next rational either.

Comment: If $p$ is some rational number bigger than $0.10$, then we can always fit another rational number $q$ between $p$ and $0.10$ by defining $q = \frac{0.10 + p}{2}$.  This may give you some insight as to why there is no notion of 'next biggest number' for the rationals

Comment: nice helps! Seems like circular logic also have big advantages.

Comment: What do you mean by circular logic?

Comment: @Tobias the back and forth fluctuations from 0 to 1 is a fluctuation. While Natural numbers are straight fall into infinity. Shouldnt this be also applied to decimal point numbers i.e, a straight fall into zero. The addition + operator is 'as is' in decimal point numbers while the multiplication * gives you a small number which is contrary to natural numbers.

Comment: I have no idea whatsoever what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Tobias I am present within the number line between 0 and 1:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no immediate successor of $0.1$ within the real (or rational) numbers; just take numbers like

\begin{align*}
&0.1 \\
&0.01 \\
&0.001 \\
&0.0001 \\
&\vdots
\end{align*}

What we *can* say, however, is that

$$0.1 < 0.11 < 0.2$$

This is because the first number represents $10$ parts of $100$, the next represents $11$ parts, and the third represents $20$ parts.

Comment: don't you think that an axiomatic amendenment is required then?

Comment: @WaqarAhmad No. Immediate successors aren't terribly useful in this context, and there's no need for them.